# django filter items by query params if one param is None

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I have get request `GET /themes` with query params:
`category_id: integer`
`level: integer`

it's maybe `GET /themes?category_id=1&level=1` or `GET /themes?category_id=1` etc

So I need get items by filter:

```py
def get(self, request):
    query = request.GET
    category_id = query.get('category_id')   # return value or None
    level = query.get('level')               # return value or None
    items = Theme.objects.all()
    qs = items.filter(category_id=category_id, level=level)
```

But `category_id` and `level` can be None, and I need change code `qs = items.filter(category_id=category_id, level=level)` if params is None

My code:

```py
if category_id and level:
    qs = items.filter(category_id=category_id, level=level)
elif not category_id and level:
    qs = items.filter(level=level)
elif category_id and not level:
    qs = items.filter(category_id=category_id)
else:
    qs = items.filter()
```

But I think it's a terrible code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with two checks:

```
qs = items
if category_id:
    qs = qs.filter(category_id=category_id)
if level:
    qs = qs.filter(level=level)
```

But I would advise using [**`django-filter`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter): this has more support for this, and can easily render a form to help you render a filter at the frontend of your app.